# How to get a list of files from all sub-subfolders in all subfolders?

Tags: windows, file, command-line, directory, subdirectory

I have a `folder` with several `subfolders`. Each `subfolder` has several `sub-subfolders`, and each `sub-subfolder` has several files, like so

```
folder
|____subfolder1
     |_________sub-subfolder1
     |         |______________file1
     |         |______________file2
     |         |______________file3
     |_________sub_folder2
     |         |______________file4
     |         |______________file5
     |         |______________fileN
     subfolder2
     |_________sub-subfolder2
     |
     etc
```

I know to get the files from a subfolder I can do

```
dir /s/b/o:gn
```

However, in this case this gives me `sub-subfolder1` and `sub-subfolder2`. I want to get `file1`, `file2`, `file3`, `file4`, etc.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will give you the full path to the filenames
- launch it in `folder` or add `"c:\path\folder"` after the `/r`

```
@echo off
for /r %%a in (*) do echo %%a
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

**dir /s/b/o:gn | sort**

Expected result:

```
folder
folder\subfolder1
folder\subfolder1\sub-subfolder1
folder\subfolder1\sub-subfolder1\file1
folder\subfolder1\sub-subfolder1\file2
folder\subfolder1\sub-subfolder1\file3

folder\subfolder1\sub-subfolder2
folder\subfolder1\sub-subfolder1\file4
```

Just in-case I am missing your question, you could also specify the sub-folder:

```
dir c:\folder\subfolder1 /s/b/o:gn | sort
```